# Name for changing middle note in chord

Tags: chord-theory

I want to know how the name of the chord would change in an Fmaj for example. 
let's say that instead of

> F , A , C

I played

> F ,  A# ,  C

What would it now be called? Sorry if it's obvious, I'm kind of new to this stuff

Answer (score 2):

F, A#/B♭, C would be an Fsus4 chord. The reason why is because you’re “suspending” or omitting the *third*- A, and replacing it with the *fourth*- A#/B♭

The F chord is made of F (root), A (third), and C (fifth), because the F major scale is F(1), G(2), A(3), **A#/B♭(4)**, C(5), D(6), and E(7). Technically, we should just refer to it as a B♭ instead of A# for the F major scale.

Here is some easy-to-understand information about suspended chords:

https://arisbassblog.com/sus2-sus4-sus7-just-plain-sus-suspense/